# TextFormField overlapped with keypad For Flutter added in existing android app

Tags: android, flutter

I am added text field in a flutter, but the keypad is overlapping with a text field when we added this in Flutter as view in the existing android app. if the same code runs independently as only Flutter application it will work.

```
TextFormField(
      focusNode: payTMFocus,
      controller: payTMController,
      inputFormatters: [
        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
      ],
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Enter mobile number",
          filled: true,
          hintStyle: getTextStyle(),
          hasFloatingPlaceholder: true),
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.length != 10) {
          return "Enter valid mobile number";
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    )
```

tried seting true to  `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` for root `Scaffold`

Github issue link -https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47107

Answer (score 0):

By overlapping means i guess you are not able to see textField as keypad shows over it.

If this is the case then you can use SingleChildScrollView to give scrollable view to area in which your text field is.

```dart
child:SingleChildScrollview(
...//container or column or some other widgets you have above in hierarchy
    child:TextFormField(
      focusNode: payTMFocus,
      controller: payTMController,
      inputFormatters: [
        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
      ],
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Enter mobile number",
          filled: true,
          hintStyle: getTextStyle(),
          hasFloatingPlaceholder: true),
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.length != 10) {
          return "Enter valid mobile number";
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    )
),
```

Hope this helps ! please comment if you are expecting some another solution. 
happy to help :)

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47107 posted in github